# How to put `0.pool.ntp.org` in `/etc/nftables.conf` without any error?

Tags: configuration, syntax-error, ntp, ntpd, nftables

In `/etc/nftables.conf`,I have `define ntp_server={ 0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org, 3.pool.ntp.org }`,
`0.pool.ntp.org` ***start with number***,then I meet error when `nft -f`.

```
$ sudo nft -v
$ nftables v0.9.0 (Fearless Fosdick)
$ sudo nft -f /etc/nftables.conf
/etc/nftables.conf:8:7-19: Error: syntax error, unexpected string, expecting comma or '}'
     0.pool.ntp.org,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/etc/nftables.conf:9:6-6: Error: syntax error, unexpected number
     1.pool.ntp.org,
     ^
/etc/nftables.conf:10:6-6: Error: syntax error, unexpected number
     2.pool.ntp.org,
     ^
/etc/nftables.conf:11:6-6: Error: syntax error, unexpected number
     3.pool.ntp.org
     ^
/etc/nftables.conf:12:1-1: Error: syntax error, unexpected '}'
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/963665/how-should-nftables-rules-using-hostnames-be-rewritten-to-deal-with-multiple-add) post? You may be better off asking on [sf] or [su]

Comment: smells like the error is on the previous line; post cat /etc/nftables.conf output please

Answer (score 0):

The ntp.org pools contain many hosts, so `0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org, 3.pool.ntp.org` will resolve to different IP address as you query them over time.

I suggest using a named set and updating it with a script periodically.